# bottomappbar problems

Tags: java, android, button

hi I'm trying to implement the BottomAppBar  but menu item not work and just show in activity
menu this

app_bar_menu.xml

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menuAboat"
    android:title="about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuExite"
    android:title="exit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/app_bar_menu"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
     import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.widget.Toolbar;
    import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  BottomAppBar  mBottomAppBar=findViewById(R.id.bar);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomAppBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.app_bar_menu);

    }
```

Comment: i am item select by this  onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).